# TypeScript: как преобразовать строку в String Literal?

Tags: typescript

Допустим, у меня такой String Literal:

```
type Style = 'classic' | 'modern' | 'future';
```

Откуда то извне (например, через Ajax-запрос) мне прилетела строка с указанием стиля:

```
const sAjaxStyle: string;
```

Как преобразовать `sAjaxStyle` в `Style` при дефолтном значении (если в `Style` не найдется соответствующего значения), например, `'classic'`?
Не писать же мне функцию типа:

```
function convertStringToStyle(s: string): Style {
  if (s == 'modern') return 'modern'
  else if (s=='future') return 'future'
  else return 'classic';
}
```

и постоянно её расширять? Должен же быть способ как то "автоматически" перебрать?

Answer (score 0):

Защитное программирование требует примерно так и писать. Ну, можно чуть сократить число строковых литералов в коде:

```
function convertStringToStyle(s: string): Style {
  if (s == 'modern' || s == 'future' || s == 'classic') 
    return s;
  else
    throw 'Wrong style value: ' + s;
}
```

Если же вы считаете что на другой стороне не может быть ошибок, либо в данном конкретном месте решаете последовать принципу GIGO (Garbage In - Garbage Out) - то можно воспользоваться приведением типа:

```
const style = <Style>sAjaxStyle;
```

Comment: не хочется постоянно расширять функцию convertStringToStyle после расширения Style
Неужели нет способа понять, что строка удовлетворяет строковому литералу? Ну что-то типа:
if (stringValidLiteral('modern', Style)) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, я нашел способ - нужно использовать enum вида:

```
enum Style { classic='classic', modern='modern', future='future' }
```

Немного избыточно, но позволяет легко написать универсальную функцию конвертации:

```
function convertStringToStyle(s: string): Style {
  const res = Style[s];
  if (!s) res = Style.classic;
  return res;
}
```

Если нужно вывести стиль в строку, то тоже просто:

```
var style: Style = Style.classic; // Для примера
var s: string = style.toString();
```

Comment: извините, ошибся. Вместо
if (!s) res = Style.classic; должно быть if (!res) res = Style.classic;